# Duplicates in RecyclerView - SortedList

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bluetooth-lowenergy, sortedlist

I'm struggling with duplicates in my recycler view adapter. 
This is the scenario:
I have an application that scans for BLE devices and updates a list with device name, address and device RSSI. 
The list should be ordered by RSSI value (DESC). I've implemented SortedListAdapterCallback in my Adapter and ordering works, however the adapter duplicates the device in the list every time an update is received for an existing device (E.g. device rssi changed).
This is my adapter:

```kotlin
class SortedDeviceAdapter(private val mContext: Context,
                          private val mClickListener: DeviceItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SortedDeviceAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val mDevices: SortedList<BLEDeviceWithRssi>

    init {
        mDevices = SortedList(BLEDeviceWithRssi::class.java, object : SortedListAdapterCallback<BLEDeviceWithRssi>(this) {
            override fun compare(o1: BLEDeviceWithRssi, o2: BLEDeviceWithRssi): Int = o2.rssi - o1.rssi

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: BLEDeviceWithRssi, newItem: BLEDeviceWithRssi): Boolean = oldItem.device.name == newItem.device.name

            override fun areItemsTheSame(item1: BLEDeviceWithRssi, item2: BLEDeviceWithRssi): Boolean = item1.device.address == item2.device.address
        })
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                    viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_device, parent, false)
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        val currentDevice = mDevices.get(position)
        holder.tvDeviceName.text = currentDevice.device.name
        holder.tvDeviceAddress.text = currentDevice.device.address
        holder.tvRssi.text = mContext.getString(R.string.rssi, currentDevice.rssi)
        val bondState = currentDevice.device.bondState
        when (bondState) {
            BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED -> holder.ivBondStatus.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_bonded))
            BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE -> holder.ivBondStatus.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_ble))
        }
        holder.btConnect.setOnClickListener { mClickListener.onConnectButtonClicked(currentDevice) }
    }

    fun addDevice(device: BLEDeviceWithRssi) {

        mDevices.add(device)
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mDevices.size()
    }

    fun clearList() {
        mDevices.clear()
    }


    interface DeviceItemClickListener {
        fun onConnectButtonClicked(device: BLEDeviceWithRssi)
    }

    class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        internal var tvDeviceName: TextView
        internal var tvDeviceAddress: TextView
        internal var tvRssi: TextView
        internal var btConnect: Button
        internal var ivBondStatus: ImageView


        init {
            ivBondStatus = v.findViewById(R.id.ivBondStatus)
            tvDeviceName = v.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceName)
            tvDeviceAddress = v.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceAddress)
            tvRssi = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRssi)
            btConnect = v.findViewById(R.id.btConnect)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = SortedDeviceAdapter::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

Each time that my bluetooth service discovers a device I call addDevice function  in my adapter with the aim to add/update the device on the list. Unfortunately if the device exists in the list a duplicate is added. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: how are you adding device to your data source.

Comment: are you sure that you arent getting duplicates in your scan results?

Comment: I'm not sure that my advice can help you or not, but please try to call notifyDataSetChange when you addDevice.

Comment: maybe you should add a check to your addData method, to see if that data is already added to the list, if so don't add it, if not do add it?

Comment: @KaranMer i'm using addDevice function. My "device discovered" callback comes from BLEScanner  mBLEScanner.startScan(new ScanCallback() {}

Comment: shouldn't you be clearing your list before adding new data?

Comment: @MidasLefko ScanCallback unfortunately works like that, I tried to set new ScanSettings.Builder().setCallbackType(CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH).build(); but after that I'm not getting any result :(

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi if that is the case then you it sounds like your issue is not with the SortedList but with the ScanCallback. You should ask another question.

Comment: @MidasLefko I don't think that the problem stays in the ScanResult. If I change the implementation of compare interface to 'override fun compare(o1: BLEDeviceWithRssi, o2: BLEDeviceWithRssi): Int = 0' I obviously lose the ordering by rssi but I also get rid of the duplicates